# mysql get table structure with column collation

Tags: mysql

I need to get table full structure as one string.

I use `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table` but lack column collation information

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `col_1` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col_2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`col_1`),
  KEY `col_2` (`col_2`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Espected:

Instead `col_2 varchar(255) NOT NULL,`

I want `col_2 varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,`

One strange thing:

I don't understand why certains tables show also the column colation with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` but others no. However if I look the structure table in phpmyadmin all tables show column collation (when the column is varchar or text type)

**One last note:**

If I use `SHOW FULL COLUMNS` ... all columns have also their collation info (even if are showing or not in `SHOW CREATE TABLE`)

So if I have not other option I try to recreate the creation table string manually from `SHOW FULL COLUMNS` result. But i think that this is a hard and risky work ...

All that I need to use in a personal tool to compare when have structure change (between two servers)

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know what collation is and what charset is? I'm asking because people usually get confused about what each of those actually does.

Comment: In principle yes but I need to use this in a personal tool (to synchronize compare data and strucure) and just for this I want to see if there are modifications in the structure

Comment: _“I don't understand why certains tables show also the column colation with SHOW CREATE TABLE but others no”_ - probably because some of those columns were explicitly given their own collation, whereas others don’t have one specified themselves, and therefor take over the collation from the table or database. _“However if I look the structure table in phpmyadmin all tables show column collation ”_ - that might simply be PMA looking up the collations on table/database level, just so that it can present you a consistent view.

Comment: If the collation is set in the create table statement, and is different from the table collation (maybe?), it will show in the show create. If a column collation/character set isn't set when you create the table, it won't show in the show create statement results.

Comment: Just exporting the table structure using PMA should give you a CREATE TABLE statement that contains everything necessary to replicate the same table setup already.

Comment: @CBroe ... I have tried now. But same result (so certains have collation info certains not) ... I think @ Solan Thrasher have reason: So certains tables are created without collation set ... and after certain time .. I have changed in PMA to use default collation. So I think the new tables what use default collation are not show this info

Comment: _“But same result”_ - I did not say that I expect this to fulfill your arbitrary requirement regarding what _code_ it will create for you; but that I expect that what PMA export produces should be able to recreate the structure 1:1 when imported elsewhere, including what collations are specified where. _“(so certains have collation info certains not)”_ - you still seem to think that this would constitute a problem in any way; until you give actual proof of that, I simply doubt it.

Comment: The problem is because this result I compare (In my tool) with column info obtained trough `SHOW FULL COLUMNS` ... and in this result all columns have specified their collation (even if in `SHOW CREATE TABLE` not shown .... And on the next check cheat my tool that believes there are modifications